# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array

Tags: wordpress

Am trying to fetch user data from wordpress table. When I put the data into an array it shows me an fatal error.

This is my php code:

```
$getuser_data = $wpdb->get_results($user_query);
$userdata = array();
        foreach($getuser_data as $data)
        {

            $userfeed['username'] = $data->user_login;
            $userfeed['name'] = $data->user_email;
            $userfeed['email'] = $data->display_name;

            $userfeed['user_id'] = $data->ID;
            $userfeed['profile_pic'] = get_wp_user_avatar_src($data->ID);
            $usercount = count($getuser_data);


        }
        $userdata[] = $userfeed;
```

Its showing the fatal error Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in last line $userdata[].
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There might be something wrong with the `$user_query` and as a result `$wpdb->get_results($user_query)` is returning `WP_Error` object instead of the query result. Wrap the code inside the following block and check what's the error.

```
if( !is_wp_error( $getuser_data ) ) {
  $userdata = array();
  foreach($getuser_data as $data)
  {

    $userfeed['username'] = $data->user_login;
    $userfeed['name'] = $data->user_email;
    $userfeed['email'] = $data->display_name;

    $userfeed['user_id'] = $data->ID;
    $userfeed['profile_pic'] = get_wp_user_avatar_src($data->ID);
    $usercount = count($getuser_data);

    $userdata[] = $userfeed;
  }

} else {
  echo $getuser_data->get_error_message();
}
```

Comment: Thanks gul, but I have tried the same last time but it doesn't work, and there is more problem, $userdata[] shows just one row instead of showing all data.

Comment: Move the `$userdata[] = $userfeed;` line inside the foreach block. That should fix the only one-row of data issue.

Also, can you share what you are actually trying to solve and the data inside `$user_query` variable?

Comment: It works like charm. You saved my day gul. Exactly I was trying to fetch the user list but it was showing just one row and in multiple rows it was showing this error. Both are solved with your trick. Thank you

Comment: You are most welcome Rohit. If it's not a problem can you please select the answer as accepted as well? Thanks in advance.